# Ruby's && operator with regards to arrays

Tags: c#, ruby, porting

I'm porting Amp's [DiffLib](https://bitbucket.org/carbonica/amp/src/7dbef9c17c2e/lib/amp/encoding/difflib.rb#cl-114) implementation [to C#](http://bit.ly/MFS4hn) and stumbled upon this very line (#114):

```
@b2j[@a[i,1]] && @b2j[@a[i,1]].each do |j|
```

Now, I got everything else ported and most tests seem to pass but I still do not understand what is this `&&` here for. I assume it is something along those lines in C#:

```
if(b2j.ContainsKey(a[i]))
{
    foreach(var j in b2j[a[i]])
```

But still not particularly sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that if `@b2j[@a[i,1]]` is not `nil` and not `false`, then continue and do an iteration with `each` it. It is used to control the flow of the program in this case.